# Meteor.js connects to, but does not publish to, remote mongo server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

So I'm connecting a develop mode instance of meteor to a remote mongo via the recommended method of including MONGO_URL::@: in order to have persistent collections for saving user state that will allow a user to come back later by loading what they had input into the app.  I can see several connections from the meteor server on the mongo server.

However, when running the app, no collections appear on the mongo server. Both "Show Collections" and db.getCollections() return nothing.

If I kill the app process and run meteor again without the remote connection, the collections appear just fine in the mongo instance that meteor starts.

Is there something special I need to do in the code with meteor to properly push collections to the remote instance? (i.e. turn off auto publish)

Comment: Your question appears too ambiguous. Explain what you want to achieve clearly and possibly post some code sample to explain what you want.

Comment: @Vaz612 did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @Jankapunkt Yes, actually! I got so wrapped up in everything that came after I forgot to verify your answer; we were indeed operating in the "default" database while all of our data was being saved to a separate one in the same mongo instance. Felt pretty silly after realizing it was something so simple. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on your local development `mongo` shell you usually enter `meteor mongo` and the shell already enters with the default database of your meteor environment.

On your server you first need to explicitly enter, which db to use:

```js
use <db_name>
db.getCollections()
```

The db you want to target with your `MONGO_URL` needs also be defined in the following pattern:

```bash
MONGO_URL=mongodb://<db_username>:<db_password>@<db_server_host>:<db_server_port>/<db_name>
```

Make sure ou use the same value for db_name when connecting and entering the databse with the `use` command.

Resources:

https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/environment-variables.html

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/